# How to define a variable for ajax, and addeventlistener/pushstate function? Javascript, not jQuery

Tags: javascript, ajax, pushstate

I am trying to sort out the console message: 'Var foo is undefined'.
Defining the variable foo, gives me the console message: Anonomyous function.
Both these are conflicting on the line: foo.addeventlistener.
Any help to this will be appreciated, I have watched javascript tutorials, maany times through now, and searched for a long time, but cannot find out what to do.

I know I can define foo to be anything I want, but what should it be so my addevent function is not anonomyous?
Or do I need some other kind of adjustement here in this code?

```
var foo = document.getElementsByTagName("li");
function Food(url) {
    var xmlhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else { // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById('text').innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
            history.pushState({}, 'foo', url);
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
    xmlhttp.send();

}

foo.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    Food(this.href);
    return false;
}, true);
```

I dont know quite how to handle this, any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: would you mind to create a fiddle which reproduces the issue?

Comment: @code-jaff 
Here is the fiddle, the problem for me is in console, what do I define foo as?`
Menu's are working and both ajax and pushstate is working.
But now, the console error foo is undefined, bothers me, as I have tried to define it as various things, then it says anonomyous function.


http://jsfiddle.net/yy8ywj4w/2/

Comment: please check my answer, your fiddle didn't define `foo` at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*The given fiddle doesn't have the function `foo` at all.* But As far as I understand your issue

```
var foo = document.getElementsByTagName("li");
```

foo is a `HTMLCollection object`, which doesn't have the method called `addEventListener`, therefore it throws the error.

What you should probably do is to iterate through the collection and bind the event Listener.

for Eg.

```
[].slice.call(foo, 0).forEach(function (el) {
    el.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        Mat(this.href); // note:: el is li element, not <a> tag
        return false;
    }, false);
});
```

or the most elegant way is to delegate events to a static common parent element

```
var nav = document.getElementById('cssmenu'); // ensures only one element
nav.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    var target = e.target;
    // simulate bubbling until captures the required tag
    while (target && target !== this && target.nodeName !== 'A') {
        target = target.parentElement;
    }
    e.preventDefault();
    Mat(target.href);
});
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for that :) I tried as you said with 
var foo = document.getElementsByTagName("li");
But that made it an anonomyous function.
This helps alot, thank you :)

Comment: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null, Does that mean I should move my script tag to the end of body, instead of inside the head tag?

Comment: Nevermind, I guess that was the issue of 'null', now no errors are there, so thanks alot! :)
gives me alot to go with, not only does it work, but I can use the different javascript words, like nodeName, learn more about that funcionality, and look more into the while loop! :)

Comment: Glad that helped, I'd prefer the second method though. :)

Comment: Yes I indeed prefer that myself :) Been looking for somethin similar, tried defining the variable foo as cssmenu by id,  but didn't adjust anything else, like the while loop!
So interesting to see what made it work, was thinking I needed a for loop, but that would make an array or something.
Would you have any pointers as to how I would make popstate work with this?
I am thinking that the object must be the cssmenu, and this.state perhaps, then url, but not quite finding out any more than that from viewing the web :)